# How to a adress lightning button from parent component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, button, parent

I have a master lightning-component with a next button and a child component  button with create. I want to a replace the create button from the child with the next button from the parent. I get the error: Uncaught Action failed: c:ModalWizard$controller$moveNext [Cannot read property 'next' of undefined]

I tried on component parent:

```
 <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Next" title="Next" onclick="{! c.moveNext }"/>
```

Controller parent:

```
 moveNext : function(component,event,helper){
     // control the next button based on 'currentStep' attribute value    
        var getCurrentStep = component.get("v.currentStep");
        if(getCurrentStep == "1"){
            component.set("v.currentStep", "2");
        }
        else if(getCurrentStep == 2){
            var objFieldsetGenerator = component.find('FieldsetGenerator');
        objFieldsetGenerator.next();
            component.set("v.currentStep", "3");
        }
    },
```

Child component on parent:

```
<c:FieldsetGenerator genericObject="{!v.genericObject}" fieldSetName="{!v.fieldset}"  title="Yo" mode="Input"/>
```

Childobject FieldsetGenerator:

```
Button:
            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.mode=='Input'? true: false}">
                <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand"
                                  type="submit" name="update" 
                                  label="{!empty(v.recordId)?'Create':'Update'}" />
            </aura:if>
```

Controller

```
  next: function(component, event, helper) {
        alert('Whoohooo');
  var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
            var fields = a.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.fields", fields);
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);  
    }
```

Comment: Did you declare an aura method inside your child component?

Comment: I did as follows:                         <aura:method name="FieldsetGenerator" action="{!c.next}" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not finding `aura:id` declaration for child component(c:FieldsetGenerator)  in your parent component code any where.

you child component declaration in parent component should be like below.

```
 <c:FieldsetGenerator aura:id ='FieldsetGenerator' genericObject="{!v.genericObject}" fieldSetName="{!v.fieldset}"  title="Yo" mode="Input"/>
```